# Laravel 5.x Forms best practice

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

as described [at the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade), the official form builder is not supported anymore since Laravel 5.0. I need to build a multi page form in my Laravel project. What is the best practice how to do that? Because it's a new project, I don't think it's best practice to use the class from Laravel Collective.

Comment: You can definitely go ahead and use the laravel Collective package for forms. Forms was removed from Laravel  but is reliable.

Comment: "I don't think it's best practice to use the class from Laravel Collective." That **is** the best practice.

Comment: You also don't have to use the form builder and just write HTML. It's really entirely up to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel doesn't come with all packages that are available in the world, doesn't mean you shouldn't freely use whatever package that you need and does the job.

So, unless you are ready to re-invent the wheel and re-implement the forms package then use the already existing and well tested package from [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/).

Comment: I tried the package from Laravel Collective and I'm convinced of it. Thanks for the help! :-)